# JSON request body always null

Tags: json, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4

This Controller

```
app.controller('BranchController', function ($scope, $http) {

    $scope.insertBranch = function () {
        var obj = { 'Code': "test", 'Name': "test", 'Address': "asd", 'Phone' : "asd", 'Email' : "asd" };
        $http.post(
            'http://localhost:21067/api/values',
            obj
            ).success(function (data) {
                alert("success " + data)
            }).error(function (data) {
                alert("error " + data);
            });
    };
});
```

This Controller Web API

```
// POST api/values
public void Post(object model)
{
    List<MvcApplication1.Models.BranchProvider.BranchViewModel> lstBranch = new List<BranchProvider.BranchViewModel>();
    lstBranch.Add(new MvcApplication1.Models.BranchProvider.BranchViewModel
    {
        Code = model.Code,
        Name = model.Name,
        Address = model.Address,
        Phone = model.Phone,
        Email = model.Email
    });
    BranchProvider branch = new BranchProvider();
    branch.InsertBranch(lstBranch);

    //return lstBranch;
}
```

i was using angular js and web api MVC 4. regardless with the web api this post json viewing by capture IE network return 500 always sent request body null, even at api return null

I'm stuck please help

Comment: Could you provide some more information? For example what are you trying to pass to your Post() methods parameter? I know it's an object but what I mean is some example object that you are trying to pass it as parameter.

Comment: i want pass all my variable obj(as json to web api) btw as defaults at post method contains [FormBody] and i was thought only return 1 parameter, so i change it with object or can be replace with my model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem resolve, problem with my IE 10, press F12 change to document standard to IE 9 thanks all

Comment: Then go ahead and accept your answer, this is perfectly fine :)

Answer (score 0):

try replacing

```
public void Post(object model)
 {
      // your code
 }
```

with

```
public void Post(string Code,string Name,string Address,string Phone,string Email)
{
   // your code
}
```

Comment: i already tried that and make the Post method cant retrieved data from json url, sorry edited question request body is null

Comment: remove the object from post as well as the call and try if the method is getting hit if not then there is some problem with your routing